# Changing android dialog vertical position (at runtime) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I need to move dialog above something when something happens at run time so I'm trying the following code but does not work:

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CategoryActivity.this, R.style.DishDetailDialogStyle);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.category_dish_dialog);
    ColorDrawable semiTransparentBg = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#90000000")); //#ALPHA, RED, GREEN & BLUE
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(semiTransparentBg);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.y = 900;

    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    dialog.show();
```

This is the style (`DishDetailDialogStyle`) applied to the dialog:

```
<style name="DishDetailDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```